# iRODS request libodbcpsql.so

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to install iRODS on my Ubuntu system. I get an error when testing databases communications.

```
ERROR: cllConnect: SQLConnect failed: -1
ERROR: cllConnect: SQLConnect failed:odbcEntry=PostgreSQL,user=xxxxxxxx,pass=xxxxxxxx
ERROR: cllConnect:          SQLSTATE: 01000
ERROR: cllConnect:  Native Error Code: 0
ERROR: cllConnect: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/libodbcpsql.so' : file not found
```

I tried installing unixODBC and odbc-postgresql but I can't find libodbcpsql any where.
Where/How can I find it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libodbcpsql was replaced with psqlodbca back in 02, install that instead.

Comment: I made a sym-link psqlodbca.so -> libodbcpsql.so and it works just fine !
Thank you very much !